# FaceBook Api for Android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to develop facebook client in android using fbrocket api.but,this api only allows input as facebook api key not the username and password.
is there any solution?..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See ["How to Acquire Your Facebook API Key"](http://www.shoutmeloud.com/how-to-acquire-your-facebook-api-key.html) more information on how you can obtain the API key you need.

If you want users to allow users to login, you must use the [OAuth 2.0 Authentication Protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).  You cannot ask users for their login information directly.  See ["Facebook for Mobile Apps"](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) for some guidance.

Comment: the problem is not getting facebook api key.i want to give userid,password as inputs.how we can achieve?

Comment: I've edited the answer with information about the authentication mechanism to use.